# How can I get all comments for a node?

Tags: 8, nodes, comments

I have have a content type (*Stuff*) with an entity reference field (*comments*) for comments (their type is *Stuff comments*) with a single field (*comment_body*).

Inside a controller, I loaded a node by its ID.

How do I get the list of all the comments for that node?

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question I guess(better alternatives are more than welcome).

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;

class SomeRepository {

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entity_type_manager;

  /**
   * ProductRepository constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    $this->entity_type_manager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  /**
   * @param $node_id
   *
   * @return array|null
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
   */
  public function getNodeComments($node_id) {
    try{
      $node = $this->entity_type_manager
        ->getStorage('node')
        ->load($node_id);
    }catch(\Exception $exception) {
      // log here
      // rethrow error or return, whatever works for you
      return NULL;
    }

    try{
      $comment_ids = $this->entity_type_manager
        ->getStorage('comment')
        ->getQuery('AND')
        ->condition('entity_id', $node->id())
        ->condition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->sort('cid', 'DESC')
        ->execute();
    }catch(\Exception $exception) {
      // log here
      // rethrow error or return, whatever works for you
      return NULL;
    }

    if(empty($comment_ids)) {
      return [];
    }

    $comments = $this->entity_type_manager
      ->getStorage('comment')
      ->loadMultiple($comment_ids);

    $comments_array = [];

    foreach($comments as $comment) {
      // Loop over and get whichever fields you want from the comments
      $comments_array[$comment->id()] = [
        'cid' => $comment->id(),
        'owner_id' => $comment->getOwnerId(), // node to which this comment belongs
        'some_field' => $comment->get('some_field')->value
      ];
    }

    return $comments_array;
  }
}
```

Comment: I posted my answer while you were posting yours :D

Comment: A minor thing - `$comment->getOwnerId();` gives you the user ID (uid) of the comment author, not the node ID.  (v. helpful answer btw, was looking everywhere.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the your node is a variable $node:

```
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  try {
    /** @var \Drupal\comment\CommentStorageInterface $storage */
    $storage = $entity_manager->getStorage('comment');
    /** @var \Drupal\comment\CommentFieldItemList $commentField */
    $commentField = $node->get('comment');
    $comments = $storage->loadThread($node, $commentField->getFieldDefinition()->getName(), \Drupal\comment\CommentManagerInterface::COMMENT_MODE_FLAT);
    if (empty($comments)){
      return;
    }
    /** @var \Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment $comment */
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
      //Logic here
    }

  } catch (\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException $e) {
  } catch (\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException $e) {
  }
```

This will get you all the comments of that node. You can play with the `\Drupal\comment\CommentManagerInterface` to get a threaded version of the comments.

Comment: This code will get all the comments independently from their type, while the OP is speaking of a single comment type.

Comment: I think it'll grab the comments referenced by the field in the node. Anyway, it was worth the try

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like

```
foreach ($stuff->get('comments')->referencedEntities() as $comment) {
   ..do whatever on entity comment ..
}
```

Comment: In the foreach you can collect the id's to an array and call "Comment::loadMultiple()" later.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a fatal `Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\comment\CommentFieldItemList::referencedEntities()`

Comment: This doesn't work in Drupal 8.7.x, as @Andrew has said, it throws a Fatal Error.